# CSS background-image not showing on element

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for my friend but when using CSS the image doesn't show up.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bobby & Rose | Pillow Service</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.wrapper {
    margin: 30px;
    background-image: url(../img/warpper.png);
}
```

My image is the header menu background but when I try the website it doesn't show up.

Comment: whats up with all the ``` ?

Comment: Can you check the name of the image? Is it really warpper.png or wrapper.png?

Comment: There's no content in the div so won't appear, define height....

Comment: Mike that was a typo, and Jrarama yes it is really wrapper.png just checked.

Comment: Just did that @BhojendraNepal but still the same not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is mistake in your HTML

```
<title>Bobby & Rose | Pillow Service</title>
```

Solution - [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g0ptwkrg/)

**HTML**

```
<title>Bobby &amp; Rose | Pillow Service</title>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../img/warpper.png);
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

If still not working at your end then you should check the path of the image it is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The DIV has no Content therefore the size is 0x0px, means no place to show the image.

Add

```
width:200px;
height:200px;
```

to your CSS. Instead of 200px youse what ever you want.

Comment: You need to add it t the wrapper part.Otherwise go into the F12 Dev Tools of your Browser and have a look. If you go to the Network Tap you should see wether or not you get the img or a 404 Message for it

Answer (score 0):

Determine the size, I also use *id* instead of *class*

CSS

```
#wrapper {
height:200px; <!--on me here -->
margin: 30px;
background-image:url('wrapper.png');
 }
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Bobby & Rose | Pillow Service</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

</div>
```

Comment: using my url, keep the .png in the same folder as the other files

Comment: for this url, the png has to be inside the "css" folder as well

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed your image name is spelled 'warpper' while the div is 'wrapper'.

Perhaps two letters being switched?

On another note - depending on the size of your image, and how you'd want it to fill the div, you may need to add:

```
background-size: contain;
```